# better multiple array sort, based on first array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I'm working to update the SVG::Graph gem, and have made many improvements to my version, but have found a bottleneck with multiple array sorting.

There is a "sort_multiple" function built in, which keeps an array of arrays (all of equal size) sorted by the first array in the group.

The issue I have is that this sort works well on truly random data, and really badly on sorted, or almost sorted data:

```
def sort_multiple( arrys, lo=0, hi=arrys[0].length-1 )
  if lo < hi
    p = partition(arrys,lo,hi)
    sort_multiple(arrys, lo, p-1)
    sort_multiple(arrys, p+1, hi)
  end
  arrys
end

def partition( arrys, lo, hi )
  p = arrys[0][lo]
  l = lo
  z = lo+1
  while z <= hi
    if arrys[0][z] < p
      l += 1
      arrys.each { |arry| arry[z], arry[l] = arry[l], arry[z] }
    end
    z += 1
  end
  arrys.each { |arry| arry[lo], arry[l] = arry[l], arry[lo] }
  l
end
```

this routine appears to use a variant of the Lomuto partition scheme from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme

I have an array of 5000+ numbers, which is previously sorted, and this function adds about 1/2 second per chart.

I have modified the "sort_multiple" routine with the following:

```
def sort_multiple( arrys, lo=0, hi=arrys[0].length-1 )
  first = arrys.first
  return arrys if first == first.sort

  if lo < hi
...
```

which has "fixed" the problem with sorted data, but I was wondering if there is any way to utilise the better sort functions built into ruby to get this sort to work much quicker.  e.g. do you think I could utilise a Tsort to speed this up? https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/tsort/rdoc/TSort.html

looking at my benchmarking, the completely random first group appears to be very fast.

**Current benchmarking**:

```
def sort_multiple( arrys, lo=0, hi=arrys[0].length-1 )
  if lo < hi
    p = partition(arrys,lo,hi)
    sort_multiple(arrys, lo, p-1)
    sort_multiple(arrys, p+1, hi)
  end
  arrys
end

def partition( arrys, lo, hi )
  p = arrys[0][lo]
  l = lo
  z = lo+1
  while z <= hi
    if arrys[0][z] < p
      l += 1
      arrys.each { |arry| arry[z], arry[l] = arry[l], arry[z] }
    end
    z += 1
  end
  arrys.each { |arry| arry[lo], arry[l] = arry[l], arry[lo] }
  l
end

first = (1..5400).map { rand }
second = (1..5400).map { rand }
unsorted_arrys = [first.dup, second.dup, Array.new(5400), Array.new(5400), Array.new(5400)]
sorted_arrys = [first.sort, second.dup, Array.new(5400), Array.new(5400), Array.new(5400)]
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("unsorted") { sort_multiple( unsorted_arrys.map(&:dup) ) }
  x.report("sorted") { sort_multiple( sorted_arrys.map(&:dup) ) }
end
```

results:

```
Rehearsal --------------------------------------------
unsorted   0.070699   0.000008   0.070707 (  0.070710)
sorted     0.731734   0.000000   0.731734 (  0.731742)
----------------------------------- total: 0.802441sec

               user     system      total        real
unsorted   0.051636   0.000000   0.051636 (  0.051636)
sorted     0.715730   0.000000   0.715730 (  0.715733)
```

**#EDIT#**

Final accepted solution:

```
def sort( *arrys )
  new_arrys = arrys.transpose.sort_by(&:first).transpose
  new_arrys.each_index { |k| arrys[k].replace(new_arrys[k]) }
end
```

Comment: `arrays.transpose.sort_by(&:first).transpose` might be worth a try.

Comment: add that as an answer and I'll upvote you! 0.004 seconds per operation ... the only (minor) issue is that it doesn't update the arrays in place

Comment: So the question is actually how to sort my SOA effectively?

Comment: depending on what SOA means https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/SOA probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an array of 5000+ numbers, which is previously sorted, and this function adds about 1/2 second per chart.

Unfortunately, algorithms implemented in Ruby can become quite slow. It's often much faster to delegate the work to the built-in methods that are implemented in C, even if it comes with an overhead.

To sort a nested array, you could [`transpose`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#transpose-method) it, then [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#sort_by-method) its [`first`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#first-method) element, and transpose again afterwards:

```
arrays.transpose.sort_by(&:first).transpose
```

It works like this:

```
arrays              #=> [[3, 1, 2], [:c, :a, :b]]
  .transpose        #=> [[3, :c], [1, :a], [2, :b]]
  .sort_by(&:first) #=> [[1, :a], [2, :b], [3, :c]]
  .transpose        #=> [[1, 2, 3], [:a, :b, :c]]
```

And although it creates several temporary arrays along the way, the result seems to be an order of magnitude faster than the "unsorted" variant:

```
unsorted   0.035297   0.000106   0.035403 (  0.035458)
sorted     0.474134   0.003065   0.477199 (  0.480667)
transpose  0.001572   0.000082   0.001654 (  0.001655)
```

In the long run, you could try to implement your algorithm as a C extension.

Answer (score 1):

I confess I don't fully understand the question and don't have the time to study the code at the link, but it seems that you have one sorted array that you are repeatedly mutating only slightly, and with each change you may mutate several other arrays, each a little or a lot. After each set of mutations you re-sort the first array and then rearrage each of the other arrays consistent with the changes in indices of elements in the first array.

If, for example, the first array were

```
arr = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

and the change to `arr` were to replace the element at index `1` (`4`) with `9` and the element at index `3` (`8`) with `3`, `arr` would become `[2,9,6,3,10]`, which, after re-sorting, would be `[2,3,6,9,10]`. We could do that as follows:

```
new_arr, indices = [2,9,6,3,10].each_with_index.sort.transpose
  #=> [[2, 3, 6, 9, 10], [0, 3, 2, 1, 4]]
```

Therefore,

```
new_arr
  #=> [2, 3, 6, 9, 10]
indices
  #=> [0, 3, 2, 1, 4]
```

the intermediate calculation being

```
[2,9,6,3,10].each_with_index.sort
   #=> [[2, 0], [3, 3], [6, 2], [9, 1], [10, 4]]
```

Considering that

```
new_array == [2,9,6,3,10].values_at(*indices)
   #=> true
```

we see that each of the other arrays, after having been mutated, can be sorted to conform with the sorting of indices in the first array with the following method, which is quite fast.

```
def sort_like_first(a, indices)
  a.values_at(*indices)
end
```

For example,

```
a = [5,4,3,1,2]
a.replace(sort_like_first a, indices)
a #=> [5, 1, 3, 4, 2]
```

```
a = %w|dog cat cow pig owl|
a.replace(sort_like_first a, indices)
a #=> ["dog", "pig", "cow", "cat", "owl"]
```

In fact, it's not necessary to sort each of the other arrays until they are required in the calculations.

---

I would now like to consider a special case, namely, when only a single element in the first array is to be changed.

Suppose (as before)

```
arr = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

and the element at index `3` (`8`) is to be replaced with `5`, resulting in `[2,4,6,5,10]`. A fast sort can be done with the following method, which employs a binary search.

```
def new_indices(arr, replace_idx, replace_val) 
  new_loc = arr.bsearch_index { |n| n >= replace_val } || arr.size
  indices = (0..arr.size-1).to_a
  index_removed = indices.delete_at(replace_idx)
  new_loc -= 1 if new_loc > replace_idx
  indices.insert(new_loc, index_removed)
end
```

`arr.bsearch_index { |n| n >= replace_val }` returns `nil` if `n >= replace_val #=> false` for all `n`. It is for that reason I have tacked on `|| arr.size`.

See [Array#bsearch_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index), [Array#delete_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) and [Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert).

Let's try it. If

```
arr = [2,4,6,8,10]
replace_idx = 3
replace_val = 5
```

then

```
indices = new_indices(arr, replace_idx, replace_val)
  #=> [0, 1, 3, 2, 4]
```

Only now can we replace the element of `arr` at index `replace_idx`.

```
arr[replace_idx] = replace_val
arr
  #=> [2, 4, 6, 5, 10]
```

We see that the re-sorted array is as follows.

```
arr.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [2, 4, 5, 6, 10]
```

The other arrays are sorted as before, using `sort_like_first`:

```
a = [5,4,3,1,2]
a.replace(sort_like_first(a, indices))
  #=> [5, 4, 1, 3, 2]

a = %w|dog cat cow pig owl|
a.replace(sort_like_first(a, indices))
  #=> ["dog", "cat", "pig", "cow", "owl"]
```

Here's a second example.

```
arr = [2,4,6,8,10]
replace_idx =  3
replace_val = 12
indices = new_indices(arr, replace_idx, replace_val)
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

```
arr[replace_idx] = replace_val
arr
  #=> [2, 4, 6, 12, 10]
```

The first array sorted is therefore

```
arr.values_at(*indices)
  #=> [2, 4, 6, 10, 12]
```

The other arrays are sorted as follows.

```
a = [5,4,3,1,2]
a.replace(sort_like_first a, indices)
a #=> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

```
a = %w|dog cat cow pig owl|
a.replace(sort_like_first a, indices)
a #=> ["dog", "cat", "cow", "owl", "pig"]
```

Comment: thanks, this is good, but I'll go with Stefan's suggestion